# Pct_change for dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, return, stock

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUvWG.png)

Hi, I am pretty new to Pythong and I have the following dataFrame with more companies on the column, first column is the date, and the rows are prices and I am trying to compute the percent change.
Using Pandas pct_change

'''prices.set_index('Date')
print(prices.pct_change(1))
'''
But I get the following error TypeError: ufunc true_divide cannot use operands with types dtype('

Comment: Please provide data example and do not mix you code `prices.set_index('Date') print(prices.pct_change(1))` and plain text. Follow the documentation if needed.
Possible solution is,  after setting index create a new calculated column: `prices["pct_cng"] = prices["column_name"]/prices["column_name"].shift(1) - 1`

Comment: the data can be seen in the image, was imported from csv

Comment: I have seen the image, But it is tedious to see the image and create a dataframe manually from that and post a solution. Do not get me wrong, I am trying to help from my previous experience. you can get a quick solution with providing data sample.